# Open gedit from command-line with custom Theme and forced Highlight Mode

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I need open some txt files with different themes and syntax highlights using **gedit** command in Ubuntu 18.04. With this, a clean startup of gedit would remain with the standard theme.

Something like in this example:

```
gedit ~/some.txt --theme=Darkmate --highlight=Markdown
```

Some solution?

Comment: `gedit --help` will reveal the options that gedit knows. There are tricks with environment variables to load a GTK3 application such as gedit with a different theme.

Comment: And naming your file `some.mkd` or `some.md` instead of just `some.txt` may help with the highlight issue.

Comment: Run `GTK_THEME=<Theme-Name>:<Theme-variant> gedit` to launch gedit with specific theme, e.g. `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gedit`.